# SQL query taking a lot of time to run

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have the SQL query shown here, indexes are present on the join columns. If I removed those table from my SQL query so it turns fast:

```
select * 
from student st, studentheader sh, studentversion sv
where st.rollnumber = sh.rollnumber
  and sh.rollnumber = sv.rollnumber
  and sh.latestversionid = sv.versionid;
```

Below are the indexes created on my tables.

- unique index on `studentheader (rollnumber, latestversionid)`
- non-unique index on `studentheader (sh.latestversionid)`
- unique index on  `studentversion (sv.rollnumber,sv.versionid)`

`Studentversion.version` column has many versions for a roll number.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I have many other tables in my query, so i can't use new joins, aprat from this could you please tell me what can be done to increase the performance. as it is taking some 3 minutes to run.

Comment: The **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax can handle **any number** of tables...... that's a lame "excuse" ...

Comment: Totally agree with marc_s comments... given that, please add to your question the output from running explain plan for your query

Comment: ok,  i have modified my query to use joins, but that is not resolving the performance of query.

Comment: Did you analyze the query plan and what exactly is taking much time?

Comment: Some people are unreasonably prescriptive about join syntax. It doesn't affect performance at all. However, most SQL is written with the explicit INNER JOIN notation and that makes it easier for other people to read, which matters on public sites like this.

Comment: The **simplest** way to increase your performance is to **(1)** ditch the ` SELECT *`  and select only those columns you **really need**, and **(2)** do the same with rows - don't fetch **ALL** rows, but instead add a reasonable `WHERE` condition to limit the number of rows to those that you **really, really need** ....

Comment: @astentx actually  sv.versionid column has many versions saved against rollnumber. like from 1to 7, and index is created on column sv.versionid and sv.rollnumber. which might be taking time.

Comment: @marc_s your solution is ok, but my problem is not with * sign, even if i give one column name so it is not resolving my issue.

Comment: There are a lot of things which affect the performance of a query. So it is impossible to answer your question just be looking at the SELECT statement and saying, *"do this"*. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325) about asking Oracle tuning questions: it will help you understand the information you need to provide before we can answer your question.